# How is ripgrep different from silver searcher ag?

Tags: ag, ripgrep

Are these related?

Which is faster?

Can either be limited to directory-names?

https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep

https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ripgrep (rg) and Silver Searcher (ag) both perform text searches, and both are created to be a better and faster `grep`.

Performance-wise, both appear to be similar, although benchmarks indicate that Ripgrep is faster in many cases (https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).

With the rising popularity of Ripgrep, it has been integrated into MS Visual Code 
([Visual Studio Code March 2017](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_text-search-improvements)).

Feature-wise, both seem very similar.  Command are also very similar as well.

Ripgrep:

```
rg "foo" -g "*.cpp"
```

Silver Searcher:

```
ag -G '\.cpp$' 'foo'
```

To limit search to a directory, add path to the command:

```
ag "bar" /etc/  
rg "bar" /etc/
```

Comment: on Windows, i've come to love AstroGrep. Seems the smallest, fastest GUI grep. http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/